# Problem with file uploads from China

Tags: php, html, file-upload, character-encoding

I have a web app, part of which accepts user uploads of csv files. There is a prospective client in China trialing the site.  They report that when they try to upload a file the page 'hangs' ie the 'Please wait etc...' graphic which shows while the file is uploading is staying on their page and the file doesn't get uploaded.  I have some validation in my PHP script, using the move_uploaded_file function, which checks if the file is saved correctly and shows an error message if the file move doesn't occur.  This part of the code isn't being executed which leads me to believe that the server is choking on the chinese character-encoding of the file, or even the file name.

I've sent them a file which I successfully tested from my own machine but they had the same result so I'm not 100% sure if my reasoning is correct.  Either way, I need to come up with a solution if they are to become a proper client.  Has anyone seen or solved an issue similar to this?

Answer (score 6):

This is just a wild guess, but there's no chance that this is related to the [Great Firewall of China](http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/), is it? Many of their filtering mechanisms wreak havoc with web applications.

Comment: That would be my guess as well. At the very least, it seems plausible that they are checking the content of files being "uploaded" and this is causing the actual request to time out.

Answer (score 1):

yes , I guess ,this is related to the GFW ,a lot of app can't use such as facebook ,twitter and so no. But use some proxy can out of the wall , or use vpn.